# Base64 as background-image source causes stutter and it is slow

Tags: javascript, angular, base64, indexeddb

I'm making a request to the server and getting the image url string, inside the component I convert the url to a Base64 string. And here is the code to do so " I copied it from an answer and can't find it on my history to attribute the author".

```
getBase64Image(img: HTMLImageElement) {
    // We create a HTML canvas object that will create a 2d image
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    // This will draw image    
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    // Convert the drawn image to Data URL
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
  }


  getBase64ImageFromURL(url: string) {
    return new Observable((observer: Observer<string>) => {
      // create an image object
      let img = new Image();
      img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
      img.src = url;
      if (!img.complete) {
        // This will call another method that will create image from url
        img.onload = () => {
          observer.next(this.getBase64Image(img));
          observer.complete();
        };
        img.onerror = (err) => {
          observer.error(err);
        };
      } else {
        observer.next(this.getBase64Image(img));
        observer.complete();
      }
    });
  }
```

in the html page

```
<div style="background-image:url({{item.imageKey}}); ">
</div>
```

the output of the image is around **800KB** 
I then store the base64 string in the indexeddb table, and later retrieving the string from the table to display it. My point of doing all of these hassle is to make the website load faster on later visits. But it is not what I expected since it really takes a few seconds to draw the images. For some pages that contain less images it is reasonable but it gets ugly on other pages. Is there a more efficient way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My point of doing all of these hassle is to make the website load faster on later visits.

Why not just set a cache header when you serve the image, and let the browser do the work of saving the cached image for you?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/If-Modified-Since

Comment: I would even add this one -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expires

Comment: this is like a foreign territory to me, I have to learn about it to be able to implement it and make this an answer. More explanation would be extremely helpful and appreciated.

Comment: Basically when you return the image, have your web server set an ETag header as well, or an expires header, or any of a bunch of other cache control headers.  How you do that depends on what web server you use, but then, let's say they request logo.jpg, your server will return the image, as well as an Etag for that image, let's say the tag is "ABCDEF".  If the user reloads the page, the browser will see "hey, I've fetched this image before, so give me logo.jpg unless it still has the etag "ABCDEF", in which case just tell me "no changes."

Comment: If you do an expires header, when you request logo.jpg, the server will say "here is the image, and keep using it until this expiration time."  Then, when the user reloads the page, the browser will just say "hey, I already have this image cached, I won't even request it."